# Cannot remove folder - Isilon REST API returns error 409

Tags: c#, .net, emc, isilon, onefs

I was getting a 409 error instead of 200 when trying to delete the folder via Isilon Rest API.

Below is the exception I got:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict).
```

I then had a look at the [API doc](https://www.emc.com/collateral/TechnicalDocument/docu79794.pdf), but the explanation was very generic.

> 409 Conflict: The specified request has a conflict that prevents the
>   operation from completing.

So I wasn't too sure what this error actually would indicate. What'd be the most likely cause of this error?

Comment: Is the folder empty?

Comment: @BradleySmith yes, it's empty